# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' on python

Tags: python

im not exactly sure what i am doing wrong here someone please help i keep getting this eoor: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns77l.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please copy and paste the code into the question. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Please provide all coded as formatted text in the question itself. Here's some helpful info about formatting code blocks: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using the `<` operator on a `NoneType` and an `int`.

The cause of your problem basically started because of this expression `average = print("Your average is: ", (1+2))`

As you can see, the print function returns `None`. So the `average` variable does not receive a value in return and therefore gets its `NoneType` data type.

replace

```
average = print("Your average is: ", (1+2))
```

with

```
average = (test1 + test 2)/2
print("Your average is: ", average)
```